# SCRIPT1053: Const must be initialized in IE 11, d3.js

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm using react d3.js. It crashes when running on IE 11. how to fix this problem. thanks

[SCRIPT1053: Const must be initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSarP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just read the release notes for v3.0.0.

Installing the latest 2.x fixed this issue.

For future reference, that command I used:

```
npm i d3-scale@2.2.2
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it not working. I think IE 11 can't read ES6. how to fix it

Comment: Well this is  confusing actually ... I'll do some research and if I got a solution I'll be back